# Is .Select<T>(...) to be prefered before .Where<T>(...)?

Tags: c#, linq, iterator

I got in a discussion with two colleagues regarding a setup for an iteration over an *IEnumerable* (the contents of which will not be altered in any way during the operation). There are three conflicting theories on which is the optimal approach. Both the others (and me as well) are very certain and that got me unsure, so for the sake of clarity, I want to check with an external source.

The scenario is as follows. We had the code below as a starting point and discovered that some of the *hazaas* need not to be acted upon. So, starting with the code below, we started to add a blocker for the action.

```
foreach(Hazaa hazaa in hazaas) ;
```

My suggestion is as follows.

```
foreach(Hazaa hazaa in hazaas.Where(element => condition)) ;
```

One of the guys wants to resolve it by a more explicit form, claiming that LINQ is not appropriate in this case (not sure why it'd be so but he seems to be very convinced). He's solution is this.

```
foreach(Hazaa hazaa in hazaas) ;
  if(condition) ;
```

The other contra-suggestion is supported by the claim that *Where* risks to repeat the filtering process needlessly and that it's more certain to minimize the computational workload by picking the appropriate elements once for all by *Select*.

```
foreach(Hazaa hazaa in hazaas.Select(element => condition)) ;
```

I argue that the first is obsolete, since LINQ can handle data objects quite well.

I also believe that *Select*-ing is in this case equivalently fast to *Where*-ing and no needless steps will be taken (e.g. the evaluation of the condition on the elements will only be performed once). If anything, it should be faster using *Where* because we won't be creating an extra instance of anything.

Who's right?

Comment: The third doesn't make sense with the two others : Select has no overload which takes a predicate as parameter (something like `Func<T, bool>`)

Comment: As Daniel's answer says, your two colleagues are very far away from understanding LINQ. It's a diplomatically delicate situation, but their opinion should not count *at all*.

Comment: "Where risks to repeat the filtering process needlessly and that it's more certain to minimize the computational workload by picking the appropriate elements once for all by Select." Picking the appropriate elements once and for all is precisely what _Where_ does. How would using _Where_ repeat the filtering process needlessly?

Comment: It's statements like "more certain to minimize the computational workload" that leave me thinking that your colleaugues priorities are wrong. The top priority is bug-free, maintainable code. Linq hugely improves your chances of achieving such a goal by allowing you to express filtering and transformation in terse and (ultimately, for the experienced) easier to understand code. Net effect, less bugs. Think about performance once it works properly. The hotspots are **never** where you expect them, so trying to guess where they are is usually a waste of time.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus What about `.Select(e=>new Hazaa(condition))`? I rewrote the code for compactness of the question, of course. We **do not** perform an empty call, haha.

Comment: @spender We've got that working properly already. All the three approaches passed the unit tests. Otherwise,, the discussion would be very short. :)

Comment: `.Select(e=>new Hazaa(condition))` would produce all new `Hazaa` objects with a boolean value as their constructor parameter (assuming there were such a constructor), and would tell you nothing about the original values or provide any help in finding what you're looking for.

Comment: Eric Lippert explained how Linq `Where` works in this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072126/linq-foreach-vs-foreach-if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072126/linq-foreach-vs-foreach-if)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Select` is inappropriate. It doesn't filter anything.
`if` is a possible solution, but `Where` is just as explicit.
`Where` executes the condition exactly once per item, just as the `if`. Additionally, it is important to note that the call to `Where` doesn't iterate the list. So, using `Where` you iterate the list exactly once, just like when using `if`.

I think you are discussing with one person that didn't understand LINQ - the guy that wants to use `Select` - and one that doesn't like the functional aspect of LINQ.

I would go with `Where`.

Comment: Those two guys are not at my day-job. It's just a side project I'm involved in and I know close-to-nothing about their competency level. Since we differed that much in our opinions I got afraid that maybe **I was** the one who's got something to learn on the subject. Now, it feels better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `.Where()` and the `if(condition)` approach will be the same.
But since LinQ is nicely readable i'd prefer that.

The approach with `.Select()` is nonsense, since it will not return the Hazaa-Object, but an `IEnumerable<Boolean>`

To be clear about the functions:

```
myEnumerable.Where(a => isTrueFor(a)) //This is filtering
myEnumerable.Select(a => a.b) //This is projection
```

`Where()` will run a function, *which returns* a Boolean foreach item of the enumerable and return this item depending on the result of the Boolean function
`Select()` will run a function for every item in the list and *return the result* of the function without doing any filtering.

Comment: Actually it does not add any overhead because of expression trees since there are no expression trees here (you can tell because the data source is `IEnumerable` and not `IQueryable`).

Comment: My bad. I meant like the code I added in my comment above: `.Select(e=>new Hazaa(condition))`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's also nonsense, as I explain in my comment above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by nonsense. It works (as in it produces the same result as the other approaches) but perhaps in a not recommended way. Is that hat you meant?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: The fact that it works seems strange to me and can only possibly be true because your `Hazaa` object is pretty strange or your tests have a bug. `Select` doesn't filter. If you have 10 objects before the `Select` the foreach will iterate over 10 objects after the `Select` has been applied, no matter what you do inside the `Select`. When you use `Where` the `foreach` iterates only over those elements that met the condition in `Where`.

Comment: There's a call to a method in the constructor of *Hazaa* that sends a request to a web service. When the created instance given certain conditions (which according to my suggestion can and should be caught and filtered for already in the *foreach*) is deemed as inappropriate, the connection to the server will not be initialized (or it will but the service won't do its magic). That's the "result" that we compare in the tests. Please keep in mind that I tried to post the smallest possible code piece to stipulate the question so some details had to go. I understand the surprise, though.