# Any benefit to loop with nested condition in the ReSharper way?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, foreach, resharper

When using a foreach loop with a nested condition inside, I ever write in the following way:

```
foreach (RadioButton item in listOfRadioButtons)
{
    if (item.IsChecked == true)
    {
         // sometging
    }
}
```

But I've installed ReSharper and it suggests to change this loop to the following form (removing the if and using a lambda):

```
foreach (RadioButton item in listOfRadioButtons.Where(item => item.IsChecked == true))
{
    // something
}
```

In my experience, the ReSharper way will loop two times: one to generate the filtered IEnumerable, and after to loop the results of the .Where query again.

I am correct? If so, why is ReSharper suggesting this? Because in my opinion, the first is also more reliable.

Note: The default IsChecked property of the WPF RadioButton is a Nullable bool, so it's need a == true, a .Value, or a cast to bool inside a condition to return bool.

Comment: Clearly, JetBrains knows something that you do not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072126/linq-foreach-vs-foreach-if :)

Comment: ReSharper is not very good if it suggests to use `item.IsChecked == true`

Comment: why not? IsChecked is a bool?, and not a bool

Comment: Sergey, I'm sure that in addition, it suggests getting rid of the `== true`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders no, because it is a nullable bool.......

Comment: It would be good for you to add that fact to your question.

Comment: "But I've installed ReSharper and it suggests" - does it actually suggest, or is it just letting you know it *can* change it if you want to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my experience, the ReSharper way will loop two times: one to
>   generate the filtered IEnumerable, and after to loop the results of
>   the .Where query again.

Nope, it will loop only once. `Where` does not loop your collection - it only creates iterator which will be used to enumerate your collection. Here is how LINQ solution looks like:

```
using(var iterator = listOfRadioButtons.Where(rb => rb.IsChecked == true))
{
    while(iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        RadioButton item = iterator.Current;
        // something
    }
}
```

Your original code is better for performance - you will avoid creating delegate and passing it to instance of `WhereEnumerableIterator`, and then executing delegate for each item in source sequence. But you should note, as @dcastro pointed, difference will be really small and does not worth noting until you will have to optimize this particular loop.

Solution suggested by ReSharper is (maybe) better for readability. I personally like simple `if` condition in a loop.

UPDATE: `Where` iterator can be simplified to (also some interfaces are omitted)

```
public class WhereEnumerableIterator<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private Func<T,bool> _predicate;

    public WhereEnumerableIterator(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
        _enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        while (_enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (_predicate(_enumerator.Current))
            {
                Current = _enumerator.Current;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public T Current { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_enumerator != null)
            _enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Main idea here - it enumerates original source only when you ask it to move to next item. Then iterator goes to next item in original source and checks if it matches predicate. If match found, then it returns current item and puts enumerating source on hold.

So, until you will not ask items from this iterator, it will not enumerate source. If you will call `ToList()` on this iterator, it will enumerate source sequence and return all matched items, which will be saved to new list.

Comment: This works? With the if condition it doesn't, because it is a nullable bool and can return null. To remove the == true, I would recommend "if (item.IsChecked.Value)"

Comment: @Guilherme didn't know `IsChecked` is a `Nullable<bool>`. Then yes, comparison with `true` is good option

Comment: "Your original code is better for performance." I'd like to expand on that. The performance hit is *barely* noticeable. Both solutions will still run in linear O(n) time. But, using `Where` you get a *slight* performance hit from the iterator's extra abstraction layer.

Comment: Now I understand why it loops only one time: lambda expressions have delayed execution.... I never remember that

Comment: @Guilherme you *can* execute lambda with delay. But not all LINQ operators have deferred execution. E.g. Count or ToList will execute immediately

Comment: @dcastro agree with you, I just pointed that there will be difference in performance. And it will be really small and premature optimization is a big evil :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy One question: If I add a .ToList() on the end on the Where clause, then the entire foreach executes two loops?

Comment: @Guilherme exactly - you will enumerate `listOfRadioButtons` and save filtered results to new list. And then you will enumerate new list in foreach loop

Comment: Thanks again, this is what I thought that happens before you remember me about the delayed behavior

Comment: @Guilherme I've updated answer with explanation of iterator implementation. Maybe that will be interesting to you