# foreach loop with a where clause

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I was wondering if it's possible to create a foreach loop in `C#` with a where loop. Not with a if statement inside, but and where clause in the declaring of the loop.

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach(var n in people where n.sex == male)
{
}
```

Comment: Why not method syntax `foreach(var n in people.Where(p=>p.sex == male))` ?

Comment: Not duplicate but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072126/linq-foreach-vs-foreach-if

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

Method Syntax:

```
foreach (var person in people.Where(n => n.sex == "male"))
{
}
```

Or the rather lengthy Query Syntax:

```
foreach (var person in from person in people where person.sex == "male" select person)
```

Comment: Assuming this is using LINQ or is it Lambda function?

Comment: Or with Linq syntax: `foreach (var person in from i in people where i.sex == "male" select i) { ... }`  (Not saying this is better, just listing it as a possibility.)

Comment: @Scott Yes.  The code in my comment and the code in this answer both compile to the same thing.

Comment: This is using [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx). Your code will compile down to exactly the same statement as i posted in my answer

Comment: (@YuvalItzchakov I know, just listing the Linq syntax for reference; some people may prefer it.)

Comment: @cdhowie It is called *query syntax*, not LINQ syntax.  Both syntaxes are different ways of using LINQ.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, is `people.Where(n => n.sex == "male")` executed every iteration or it caches it in the first iteration?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like what you need is a lambda expression to limit the items the foreach look works with.

Based on your limited example, something like this:

```
foreach(var n in people.Where(n => n.sex == male))
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As Yuval's answer and its comments point out, you can put any query -- in either "fluent" or "query syntax" form -- as the collection expression. This leads to awkward constructions like:

```
foreach(var person in from person in people where person.sex == male select person)
```

Not only is this very verbose, in the example I have given here the simple name `person` is used both in the query and the loop declaration. You might wonder why that is even legal, as normally C# is strict about ensuring that a simple name has only one meaning in a given local variable scope.  The answer is here: http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/05/simple-names-are-not-so-simple-part-two/

IIRC the C# design team briefly considered a syntax such as you describe, but never got even as far as writing a specification. It's a nice idea but it just wasn't a sufficiently awesome language extension to make it to the top of the list. This would be a nice feature to pitch for a future version of C#.