# What is the proper way for iteration of two collections using LINQ to check for a matched property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to check if a user is a member of a group based on the results from the Graph Client SDK and a selection of groups chosen by the user in a front-end .NET Core website. I have a working sample using two `foreach` loops but I'm certain there is a cleaner way by using a lambda. I've used them in the past but I'm just a bit stuck on syntax I think.

I have a list of `GroupModel` and a collection of Microsoft Graph Client SDK results:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<GroupModel> Groups { get; set; }

public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    var graphServiceClient = await GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();
    IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage memberOfGroups = await graphServiceClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();

    var isMember = false;

    //cycle through groups the user is a member of
    foreach (var member in memberOfGroups)
    {
        //cycle through groups used for permission to the asset
        foreach (var group in Groups)
        {
            if (group.GroupId == member.Id)
            {
                //user is a member of the group being set
                isMember = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isMember)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("GroupsError", "You are not a member...");
    }
}
```

I have tried the following however it gives me an error:

```
bool isMemberLambda = Groups.ForEach(g => memberOfGroups.Contains(m => m.Id == g.GroupId));
```

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Directory.Object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I believe you can use a forEach with a where clause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412158/foreach-loop-with-a-where-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linq:

```
 var isMember = memberOfGroups.Any(mog => Groups.Any(g => g.GroupId == mog.Id));
```